# What wrong with my dafny method. simple method postcondition might not hold

Tags: dafny

I am new to Dafny, and I am trying to write a code to computer 5*m-3*n without using *.

Can anybody tell me what wrong with my code? I think it is the invariant and decrease.

```
method CalcTerm(m: int, n: nat) returns (res: int)
  ensures res == 5*m-3*n;
{
  var m1: nat := abs(m);
  var n1: nat := n;
  res := 0;

  while (m1!=0)
    invariant m1>=0
    decreases m1
  {
    res := res+5;
    m1 := m1-1;
  }

  if (m<0) { res := -res; }

  while (n1!=0)
    invariant n1 >= 0
    decreases n1
  {
    res := res-3;
    n1 := n1-1;
  }
}
```

But it keep saying that:

```
A postcondition might not hold on this return path. 29  2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that the issue has to do with loop invariants. I recommend reading the two sections of the [Guide](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorial/Guide) on Assertions and Loop Invariants.

Dafny "summarizes" the effect of a loop using *only* its invariants. So after the second loop in your method, Dafny will only know that `n1 >= 0` and that the loop has terminated, so actually `n1 == 0`. This is not enough information to prove your postcondition: you need a stronger invariant. Here's one that might help you make progress

```
invariant res == 5 * m - 3 * (n - n1)
```

This invariant computes the value of `res` in terms of how many iterations of the loop have executed so far (`n - n1`). If you add this invariant to the second loop, you'll get a new error (progress!) that says it might not hold on entry. This means that Dafny is able to prove your postcondition, but not able to establish that the new invariant is true after the first loop is done. This is again because the invariant on the first loop is too weak.

Maybe this gives you enough information to try coming up with another invariant for the first loop on your own. Feel free to ask more questions here if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you. I learn the definition of invariant and I have already solved it with you help.

Comment: Given the numeric nature of this problem, you may be helped by the following episode of Verification Corner, where the example is a similar problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spcfzbisBv4